# Couchdb Javascript reference

Tags: javascript, documentation, couchdb

**Background:**

Trevor would like to set up some couchdb shows and views that require a timestamp to be appended to the requesting URL, along with some other parameters, in order to easily make the time of request and other stuff part of the output of the view.

Trevor would also like to work with parameters that use any of various encoding schemes, such as Base64 or MD5 or SHA256.

**Question:**

1) Is there a Javascript reference for the types of calls that Trevor can use inside his Javascript code? The specific platform is:

```
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.0.2","cloudant_build":"1202"}
```

2) If there is no general-purpose reference available, can Trevor leverage documentation from some other project, (such as Node.js) in order to know the type and variety of Javascript function calls, and general syntax and programming conventions, avaliable to him in his couchdb shows and views?

Comment: In CouchDB, JS is executed using SpiderMonkey, (which is Mozilla's JS implementation) so any of [their docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) will apply.

Comment: Greetings Dominic, if you have a chance, would you mind migrating your comment to an answer so it can be upvoted and easily cross-referenced? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CouchDB, JavaScript code is executed using the SpiderMonkey engine, which is Mozilla's implementation. Therefore, any of [their documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) will apply.